# Determining the maximum value of a multivariable function under 4 inequality constraints.(Math GRE subject test 9768 Q.25)

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, gre-exam, constraints

> [image]

I know that I should use Lagrange multiplier method, but how with the inequality constraints? could anyone help me please?

Comment: Don't use Lagrange multiplier. Draw a picture.

Comment: @Jack.....ok I will do .....but I would like to ask u a question .....how did u put this light pink frame around my question above?

Comment: I added the character `>`.

Comment: @Jack   where did u add it?

Comment: You can see where I added it by hit the `edit` button under your post.

Comment: The key word for your question is "linear programming": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Comment: @Jack  but how can I draw a picture? ..... the time in the exam to answer this question should not exceed 2.5 minuites..... and also I do not know how to draw.

Comment: Not difficult. See http://math.tutorvista.com/algebra/graphical-method-of-linear-programming.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer should be D.

Often you can solve these types of problems without needing any fancy math.

Looking at $f$ we see that $f$ will be as large as possible when $x$ is as large as possible and when $y$ is as small as possible. The first two inequalities tell us that the maximum $x$ can be is 2 and the smallest $y$ can be is 0. We can see that these satisfy the other two inequalities so we are done.

Comment: yeah I solved it, it is so easy question.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)=\text{First Term }- \text{ Second Term}$

$f$ will be maximised when $\text{First Term}$ is maximised and $\text{ Second Term}$ is minimised.

Note that first term is maximised when $x=2$ (Because $x \le 2$). Also note that the second term is minimised when $y=0$ (Because $y \ge 0$). Clearly, when $x=2$ and $y=0$, the conditions $x+y \ge 1$ and $y-x \le 0$ are already satisfied.

Therefore, the required value is $f(2,0)=5(2)-4(0)=10$, which is option $\text{D}$.